# Is there a way to export a csv file with ";" separator for the columns?

Tags: python, format, export-to-csv, separator

I have a code that ends like

```
            line = format("%s\t%s\t%.3f\t\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg))
            self.output_file.write(line)

bbdl = BbDownloader()
bbdl.write_tick_data(output_filename="TEST1.csv")
```

And it generates a csv file. However, this file has space, like " ", as separators for each column. I figured there must be something I could do to generate a file with ";"  as separators, so I tried

```
line = "{:;}".format("%s\t%s\t%.3f\t\t%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh))
```

But it didn't work. It generated the file, but it never stopped loading.

Comment: What is a `BbDownloader`? Can you show a complete example of your code rather than the tail end of it? And when you say "it never stopped loading," do you mean your CSV file fails to load in something like Excel?

Comment: Hard to say with partial snippets only (especially if using some 3rd-party modules). https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv offers the possibility to do what you need.

Comment: @CristiFati this link already helped a lot! Can't say yet if it'll work it out for me, but thank you very much nonetheless!

Comment: @wkl unfortunately I can't because of my work, but I understand that makes it especially difficult to find any answer. I use DataFlame to write my code, and when I tried generating the csv file there, technically there weren't any errors but the file didn't open, only kept loading.

Comment: Trivial to do with Python's built-in `csv` module.